# how to insert area of polygon into a column named area in a polygon map in cartodb?

Tags: postgis, carto

```
SELECT ST_Area(the_geom) FROM cartodb_query
```

gives the area but trying to insert it into an area column using:

```
UPDATE cartodb_query SET area = ST_Area(the_geom)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: How does it not work, is there an error? Silly question, but I assume the column area exists and is of the correct data type?

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget to use semicolon at the end of the query?

Comment: Semicolons are not needed in the CartoDB UI for single statements. :) The query failed because of an issue in the user account.

Comment: An issue in the user account... Has the user permissions to edit the table/update the column?

Answer (score 2):

The query you're using is correct, but a detail for you to take into account.

ST_Area [result will be expressed in SRID units](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Area.html) if you use directly the_geom. If you want to get the area in square meters, you need to cast your geometry to geography, by using:

```
UPDATE cartodb_query SET area = ST_Area(the_geom::geography)
```